# jQuery.parseHTML security considerations

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

In the API for the jQuery.parseHTML method, there's a paragraph that reads

> However, it is still possible in most environments to execute script indirectly, for example via the `<img onerror>` attribute. The caller should be aware of this and guard against it by cleaning or escaping any untrusted inputs from sources such as the URL or cookies.

I'm fairly new to these kinds of security considerations — I had no idea about the onerror attribute, for example — so what do I need to look for in order to be safe? Is it okay to just run something like:

```
function stringToDOM(raw_string) {
    var escaped = _.escape(raw_string);    // lodash 3.2.0
    return $.parseHTML(escaped);
}
```

or is there more that I need to do to be safe?

Thanks.

Comment: `_.escape` and `$.parseHTML` do two different things. `_.escape` encodes HTML for display as text. `$.parseHTML` parse the HTML, and removes `<script>` stags in the process. `$.parseHTML` will not add additional escaping, just convert the string it to a text node. You can see the attack with this: `$.parseHTML('<img src="#" onerror="alert(1);" />');`.

Comment: What do you want `stringToDOM("<img onerror>")` to be? Do you want it to be an error? Do you want it to be `"&lt;img onerror&gt;"` etc. Do you want `stringToDom` to actually parse elements?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara `var str = '<img src="#" onerror="alert(1);" />';
var res = str.split(" ").filter(function(html, i) {
    return html.slice(0, 2) !== "on"
}).join(" "); console.log(res);` ?

Comment: @guest271314 That filter could be bypassed, just use a different whitespace character or some other character the browser will try to error-handle. It would also potentially have negative effects on attributes like `class` or text content if called on such an element.